# Is there a PHP function like is_lob() for large object type (LOB)?

Tags: php

`is_object()` will return true if the argument is an object, but what function (or series of functions) will determine if something is a LOB (Large Object Type)?

Comment: Are you talking about `PDO::PARAM_LOB`? This doesn't use a separate type, it works with stream resources.

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to test a variable to determine if it is that. Also, is there a way to test a variable to see if it is a MYSQLI BLOB, or would it be the same function/procedure?

Comment: A BLOB is just a string in PHP.

Comment: once you retrieve something from a db, it's no longer a db data type. the db library will convert it to a native php type. blobs would generally become a php string.